# 3 phase transformer efficiency calculation

Tags: transformer, three-phase, electric-machine

This is an assignment. No matter how hard I try the answer is never what I expect. Here is the question:

Three single phase transformers, each rated at 12 kVA, 120/240V, 60Hz, are connected to form a three-phase, step-up, star/delta connection. The parameters of each transformer are

R(High) = 133.5 milli-ohms,
X(High) = 201 milli-ohms,
R(Low) = 39.5 milli-ohms,
X(Low) = 61.5 milli-ohms,
Rc(Low) = 240 ohms,
Xm(Low) = 290 ohms.
When it delivers the rated load at the rated voltage and 0.8 pf lagging, determine the line voltage, line currents and efficiency.

I will tell you what I am after. Here is what I did, but the answer is 0.92 approx. I think I am mistaken in calculating core and/or copper loss.

[image]

[image]

Comment: "*RH = 133.5 milli-ohms, XH = 201 milli-ohms, RL = 39.5 milli-ohms, XL = 61.5 milli-ohms, RC = 240 ohms, Xm = 290 ohms.*" - I have no idea what parts of the transformer equivalent circuit these apply to.

Comment: H refers to high voltage, L to low.

Comment: Although it is not mentioned, Rc and Xm are referred to low voltage, sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: If you are after efficiency all three transformers will be equally efficient so why not simplify to a single phase problem.

Comment: Does efficiency not depend on the way we make connection? That is, star delta or delta delta?

Comment: I tried to find efficiency for a single phase transformer but still I am not any close to the answer provided.

Comment: Did you calculate the same efficiency as for your 3 phase calculation? Efficiency does not depend on star or delta.

Comment: I had multiplied the losses by three in above calculation. So I divided it by 3. But I left output volt-amps 12 KVA. Maybe in the calculation I shown above I should have taken output volt-amps as 36 KVA. Then I will get the same efficiency as my 3 phase calculation.

Comment: Have I used correct approach in the solution I provided?

Comment: Please tell me if my question is not worth answering or if my mistake is too obvious. I am new to this site and this is my first question.

Comment: I don't see a mistake but I haven't given it much thought. Problem is that not many folk know much about 3 ph and asking for homework checking usually disinterests people. If I were faced with this question I'd use a simulator to check my results.